# VBA- append column to other sheet column

Tags: excel, vba

I am consolidating two sheets into one and choosing select columns to do so. The sheets are schedules for employee shifts. I have copied the first sheets(1) columns to the new sheets(3) :Date, Day of week, Time, Show Covering, Employee. I am trying to now copy the needed columns from sheets(2) to sheets(3). One of them is shift time. I need this to be added to the existing column of time which is column 3. Currently it is replacing that data. Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Copy
erow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Sheets(3).Cells(erow, 1)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Sheets(3).Cells(erow, 2)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Sheets(3).Cells(erow, 3)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Sheets(3).Cells(erow, 4)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 8).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Sheets(3).Cells(erow, 5)
Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Copy
Sheet2.Paste Destination:=Sheets(3).Cells(erow, 3)

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheet3.Columns.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a paste destination, you can append to the existing text in the cell.  Something like this:

```
Sheet3.Cells(erow, 3) = Sheet3.Cells(erow, 3) + Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)
```

Comment: I do not want to append to text in a cell. I want to append an entire column of unknown length from sheet 2 to the end of an existing column in sheet 3.

Comment: @SobiaBhatti It appears you are going row by row in your loop.  Wouldn't the loop append the entire column one cell at a time?

Comment: That's the problem, it is going row by row and instead of appending it is replacing. @FarzamMoshtagh